# Sharing variables between two source files in the same package

Tags: http, global-variables, go

I am working on a project in Go. For organization, I have the code split up into files:

- server related functions go in *server.go*
- database handling goes in *db.go*
- global variables are in *types.go*
- etc.

I declared a variable `document_root` in *types.go*, and defined it in *main.go* with:

```
document_root,error := config.GetString("server","document_root")
```

In *server.go*, I have a function to generate an HTTP status code for the requested file, and it does:

```
_, err := os.Stat(document_root+"/"+filename);
```

Upon compiling, I'm getting this error:

> "document_root declared and not used"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming in types.go, you're declaring `document_root` at the package scope. If so, the problem is this line:

```
document_root, error := config.GetString("server", "document_root")
```

Here, you're unintentionally creating another `document_root` variable local to the `main` function. You need to write something like this:

```
var err error
document_root, err = config.GetString("server", "document_root")
```

Comment: Oh, ok that fixed it. Looking at the Language Specification page, I didn't realize that := redeclares it.